# Doctrine ODM query builder return different results than raw query

Tags: php, mongodb-query, doctrine-odm, php-mongodb

I try to get some results filtered with a condition **if data does not exist or if exists and is older than...**

I have query build with PHP query builder

```
 ->addOr(
            ['interactions.lastDisplays' => ['$elemMatch' => [
                'user' => new \MongoId($id),
                'date' => ['$lte' => $date]
            ]]],
            ['interactions.lastDisplays.user' => ['$ne' => new \MongoId($id)]]
        )
```

And it logs to:

```
db.Post.find({ 
"$or": [ 
{ "interactions.lastDisplays": { 
    "$elemMatch": { "user": ObjectId("5a61bb816e0bb1542a0bc574"),
    "date": { "$lte": new ISODate("2019-06-14T13:22:01+00:00") } } } },
{ "interactions.lastDisplays.user": { 
    "$ne": ObjectId("5a61bb816e0bb1542a0bc574") } 
}] 
}).limit(25).skip(0);
```

For some reason, it does not return any results in PHP. When I copy it and run directly on a database it works fine, and all 25 results are returned.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was as simple as changing `$lte` to MongoDate.

```
 ->addOr(
        ['interactions.lastDisplays' => ['$elemMatch' => [
            'user' => new \MongoId($id),
            'date' => ['$lte' => $new \MongoDate($date->getTimestamp())]
        ]]],
        ['interactions.lastDisplays.user' => ['$ne' => new \MongoId($id)]]
    )
```

The strange thing that I don't understand yet is that it used to work with `DateTime` in other queries (but they don't have nested array conditions, so maybe it's the issue). And also that query log is pretty the same.